Return null if the parameter is more than one word
I was making a show result page in app script. The idea is the user passes their ID, then a function looks it up then returns their special ID. Then another function will look for their results from another sheet.
All of that works well until I tried to make the special ID two words (or more). The function for getting result returns null - even though  it return the result in server-side of app script.
How can I return the result if the special ID is more than one word?
Here are the codes for the webpage :
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
      if(id.checkValidity()) {
        spinner('show');
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(checkId).getIds(id.value);
        console.log("1"); 
        } else { 
          alertShow("ِEnter a value of 10 numbers"); }
        });
      

        
      function checkId(id) { 
        const idN = id;
        console.log(idN); 
        if(idN !== '404' ) {
          reportHeader.classList.remove("hidden");
        const html = `
        <h2 class="text-3xl font-bold">تقارير مجمع ${idN}</h2>
        `;
        document.getElementById("reportsHeader").innerHTML += html;
        //google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(show).getReports(idN);
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(show).getReports(String(idN));
        console.log("2");  
        } else { 
          alertShow("No data for this id");
          spinner('hide'); 
      }} 

      function show(para){
        console.log(para);
      }

And the code for server-side :
function getIds(id){
  const idN = Number(id);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("الاستعلامات");
  const data = ss.getRange(1,1,ss.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
  
  const dataFiltered = data.map(function(v){return Number(v[0])});
  const rowNumber = dataFiltered.indexOf(idN);
  if(rowNumber >= 0){
    
    return data[rowNumber][1];
  } 
  
  return '404';
}


function getReports(id){
  const uId = id.trim();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("التقارير");
  const data = ss.getRange(1,1,ss.getLastRow(),ss.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const filteredData = data.filter(function(v){return v[3].trim() === uId}).map(function(v){return [v[2],v[5],v[6],v[7],v[8],v[9],v[10],v[11],v[12],v[13],v[14],v[15],v[17],v[18]]});
  //Logger.log(filteredData);
  return filteredData;
}

Is there a way to get what I need even though the special ID is more than one word?
The Id in the first function is a number of 10 digits (1111111111), the special id is a word or words (It/it department - not in English -)

Typeof Operator and document.getElementById().value
I used typeof operator returns the type of a variable or an expression.
Also declaring variable to get the data on the spreadsheet
Script used
Code.gs
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function getIds(id) {
  if (typeof id === 'undefined' || id === null) {
    return '404';
  }

  id = id.toString().trim();  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const data = ss.getRange(1, 1, ss.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();

  const dataFiltered = data.map(function(v) { return v[0].toString().trim(); });
  const rowNumber = dataFiltered.indexOf(id);
  
  if (rowNumber >= 0) {
    return data[rowNumber][1];
  } 

  return '404';
}




function getReports(id) {
  const uId = id.trim();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const data = ss.getRange(1, 1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const filteredData = data.filter(function(v) {
    return v[3].toString().trim() === uId;
  }).map(function(v) {
    return [
      v[2], v[5], v[6], v[7], v[8], v[9], v[10], v[11], v[12], v[13], v[14], v[15], v[17], v[18]
    ];
  });

  return filteredData;
}

Index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="id" placeholder="Enter ID">
  <button id="btn">Submit</button>
  <div id="reportsHeader"></div>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
  var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
  console.log('Client-side ID:', id);
  if (id) {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(checkId).getIds(id);
  } else {
    alert("Enter a value.");
  }
});
    function checkId(id) {
      if (id !== '404') {
        var html = `<h2 class="text-3xl font-bold">تقارير مجمع ${id}</h2>`;
        document.getElementById("reportsHeader").innerHTML = html;
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(show).getReports(id);
      } else {
        alert("No data for this ID");
      }
    }

    function show(para) {
      console.log(para);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>

Sample Output
Spreadsheet

For number of 10 digits (1111111111)

For special ID

Reference

Typeof Type Operator
document.getElementById().value

